# Litz Wire Calculation

Tags: inductor, litz-wire

I want to use Litz wire for my Inductor

Peak Current = 15A

Current Density = 5A/mm2

My supplier has told he has 0.1mm diameter strands.
How should I determine number of strands and Cross section Area of whole Litz wire from strand diameter and no. of strands, so that I can verify it in my inductor calculation.

Thank You

Comment: Could this be of help? https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/631724/how-can-i-calculate-litz-wire-strands